# jQuery Ajax call not working

Tags: .net, ajax, jquery

i am just trying to make a simple Ajax call using jQuery

this is my JavaScript:

```
//Starts the game
function startGame() {                       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/StartGame"                
    });
}
```

my button:

```
<input type="image" value="twist..." src="images/play.png" class="playButton" onclick="startGame();return false;" />
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class Default : Page
    {
        private static GameEngine GameEngine
        {
            get { return new GameEngine();}
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public void StartGame()
        {
             GameEngine.StartToPlay();   
        }
    }
```

when I debug the code in Visual Studio the method `StartGame` is never called.

Can anyone explain to me what's the problem?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do, and what is it doing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made StartGame() static and now it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with .net, but it seems as if your Javascript code makes a POST request, while there's only a GET handler on the backend.

In general it's a good idea to be able to debug the functionality on each layer. For example, you can check if your request was triggered (or analyze what the problem was with [the Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) on Firefox. Chrome and Safari have similar debugging mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

From : http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

You're missing parameters (contentType & dataType) to $.ajax :

```
 function startGame() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"Default.aspx/StartGame" 
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: "{}",
         dataType: "json"
     });
 }
```

Comment: Those aren't required parameters.

Comment: ok corrected + added source.
Even with optional parameter, this solution works...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that because you are setting the request as POST and you aren't sending any POST data eg:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Default.aspx/StartGame",
   data: "name=John",
   success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
   }
 });
```

If you are just retrieving html you should use:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Default.aspx/StartGame",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    //create the game html
    $("#game").append(html);
  }
});
```